# Optimising Cross Join PostGIS Query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, ogr, geopandas

I have tried performing the query shown below via `ogr2ogr` and the `gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis()` method in geopandas.

from osgeo import ogr
import psycopg2, os

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
ogr.UseExceptions()

server = "xxxx.com"
name = "xxxx"
user = "xxxx"
pw = "xxxx"
port='5432'
lyr_name = 'ships'

conn = psycopg2.connect('connection details')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print('executing sql')
query = 'select * from ships a, ships b \
where a.dt_upload>\'2019-01-01\' and b.dt_upload>\'2019-01-01\' \
and a.det_id>b.det_id and ST_DWithin(a.ship_centroid, b.ship_centroid,100)'
#query executed below always fails
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(query,conn, 'ship_center1', crs='EPSG:4326')

ships1=gdf.iloc[:,0:7]
ships2 = gdf.iloc[:,7:]
ships2['shipcenter2'] = ships2['shipcenter2'].apply(wkt.loads)
ships2.columns = ships1.columns
new_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([ships1,ships2], ignore_index=True),crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} )
new_gdf.rename(columns={'shipcenter1':'geometry'}, inplace=True)
new_gdf.to_file('./ship_coverage.shp' )
```

Everytime I try the process gets killed. There are about a million rows in my table. How can I optimise this query to fully execute so I can either export the results as a shapefile or as a GeoDataFrame?

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: Do you have an index on `ship_centroid`? What is the SRID of this column?

Comment: Additionally, an index on`dt_upload` (and `det_id`, but I assume that is your PK?) would be beneficial.

Comment: @CL i have an index on the `ship_centroid`. It has a SRID of 4326. I will try and put in an index on the `dt_upload` column @geozelot. Thank you

Comment: 4326 is in degree, `st_dwithin(geom,geom,100)` correspond to a huuuuuge area ! Is that really what you want?

Comment: unfortunately i need all the points within 100m of each other on a global scale so i can start to form a kind of idea of higher vs lower density regions. the 100m is what I was told- what distance would you suggest ?

Comment: Your code do not indicate 100m, your code indicate 100 degres ! That correspond to several thousand kilometer !

Comment: oh i see that would make a lot of sense!- if cast the column into a geography type it should solve this problem?

Comment: off topic: you may want to change your password now...

Comment: @thesunnyscientist, what I would do is to reproject the features to another SRID where units are in meter (using `ST_Transform`). And, really, if it's not already done, change your password, stackexchange keep an historized version of your question.